# Inserir dados de um array no banco de dados pelo CodeIgniter

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, sql-insert

Estou tentando fazer um `INSERT` utilizando o CodeIgniter e gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais prática do que a usada abaixo:

**MODEL**

```
public function set_cliente() {     

    $dados = array(
        'codigo_cliente' => $this->input->post('cCodigocliente'),
        'data_cadastro' => $this->input->post('cDatacadastro'),
        'hora_cadastro' => $this->input->post('cHoracadastro'),
        'funcionario' => $this->input->post('cFuncionario'),
        'empresa' => $this->input->post('cEmpresa'),
        'representante' => $this->input->post('cRepresentante'),
        'modalidade' => $this->input->post('cModalidade')
    );   
    $this->db->insert('tb_clientes', $dados);

}
```

Teria alguma forma de fazer sem que tenha que digitar todos os campos?

Comment: O nome do campo no HTML não condiz com o nome da coluna no banco de dados, então você não conseguirá fazer com que o PHP *magicamente* saiba onde armazenar cada valor, então não, não há uma forma de se fazer isso. Mesmo que fosse, não seria recomendado, pois seria confiar muito nos dados recebidos pela requisição.

Comment: Mas se eu utilizar o mesmo nome nos campos, seria possível?

Comment: A pergunta é: existe essa necessidade? São 7 linhas de código.

Comment: As 7 linhas foram apenas para exemplo, tenho muito campos além desses.

Comment: E se algum campo não for enviado junto? Ou se forem enviados outros campos além do esperado? Qual deverá ser o comportamento da aplicação?

Comment: Sua pergunta vai de encontro com outra dúvida, o que estou querendo fazer é comum, ou é feito da forma que estava fazendo. Gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês, até mesmo pela questão de segurança, conforme questionando anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

É possível automatizar parte do processo com geração de código um mapeamento dos nomes dos campos do form com os campos da tabela. No model pode definir um atributo chamado `$campos` ele é um array onde suas chaves são os nomes dos campos do form e os valores os nomes das colunas.

Ao chamar `$this->input->get/post()` passando null como primeiro argumento e `true` como o segundo são retornados todos os campos do form em um array associativo.

No exemplo deixei `$campos` como variável local do método

```
public function set_cliente() {   
  $campos = array('id' => 'codigo', 'nome' => 'nm', 'email' => 'ml', 'idade' => 'dd');
  $valores = $this->input->get(null, true);
  $dados = array();
  foreach($valores as $k => $v){
    if(isset($campos[$k])){
        $nomeTabela = $campos[$k];
        $dados[$nomeTabela] = $v;
    }  
  }
  $this->db->insert('tb_clientes', $dados);
}
```

**Documentação:**

[CI classe input](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#class-reference)